# PHP, HTML FORM, como interagir com valores nos formulários?

Tags: php, html

Estou me aventurando um pouco com *PHP*, e me deparei com a seguinte situação.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="control label">Tipo: </label>
    <select name="teste" class="form-control">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
      <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Existe alguma maneira de obter esse valor que estou atribuindo ao *select*, e atribuir a uma variável dessa forma:

```
<?php $a = $_POST["teste"];?>
```

E usar essa variável `$a` em outro lugar?

Comment: Olá, seja bem-vindo ao SOpt! Você tentou fazer isso por si mesmo?

Comment: sim, só estou me aventurando um pouco com php pra ver até onde vai... e me deparei com isso. é possivel fazer, ou tem algo diferente em php q faça isso?

Comment: ou por acaso tem alguma outra forma de se fazer isso por outra linguagem?

Comment: ou se não tiver, por acaso tem como restringir perguntas de outro select dependendo desse dai?

Comment: Você está dizendo 'salvar' esta variável para acesso posterior?

Comment: Claro: sessão, cookie, requisições assíncronas, cache. Aqui me pareceu que vc quer manipular o formulário antes de enviar. Se for esse o caso, vc precisa de `Javascript`.

Comment: Sim, no caso... o que eu procuro em especifico de javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Olá.

Não sei se entendi muito bem a sua dúvida. Mas o básico da interação HTML + PHP seria colocar o select dentro de um form, com o action apontando para a página que irá conter a variável que você quer usar, e com o método que pode ser POST ou GET. Por exemplo:

Página_do_formulario.html

```
  <form action="pagina_da_variavel.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="teste" class="control label">Tipo: </label>
        <select name="teste" class="form-control">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
          <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </form>
```

pagina_da_variavel.php

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['teste']){
  $a = $_POST['teste'];
}
else{
  $a = "Nada foi selecionado no select";
}

echo $a;

?>
```

Comment: ola, não quero observar meus dados depois de um submit, gostaria de observar ele antes de submeter para usa-lo como restrição para outro select p.ex.

Comment: Então sua pergunta deve ser editada pra fazer entender que vc quer manipular o form antes de enviar. Essa atribuição que vc fez (`<?php $a = $_POST["teste"];?>`) só acontece após o envio.